# Which flag would have been appropiate for this comment to get deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comment-flags, specific-comment

Recently I came across the question *[How to extract the UI label texts using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395405/how-to-get-the-ui-lable-name-back-using-selenium-webdriver#)* where apparently as per [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50395405/1) it appeared the OP initially hadn't provided the relevant HTML within the question. But later the OP has provided the HTML as a comment. Fair enough.

I decided to update the question with the HTML from the comments. While editing the question it was evident the HTML was already present within the question, but it wasn't visible due to an indentation issue. Hence I went ahead and indented the HTML for proper visibility.

But now the comment is no longer necessary, and I feel should be deleted. I do have the option to raise a flag, but I am unsure which flag suits this *usecase* as follows:

- *rude or abusive - This comment violates our "Be Nice" policy.*: No, it's not rude at all.
- *no longer needed - This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary.*: No, *Review Team* will have no clue that the HTML is already present within the question and I don't have an option to pass this information. The flag will be declined.
- *in need of moderator intervention - A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!*: No, I don't want to engage a moderator's attention for a trivial issue.

So what would be my correct coarse of action to get the comment deleted?

Comment: Why is "no longer needed" not an option? Won't reviewers see that the HTML is now properly in the question because you fixed it?

Comment: I just flagged the comment as "no longer needed". If it's marked helpful, you'll know what the answer to this question is.

Comment: @coldspeed Would be a rigged judgement :) Review Team members are vigilant on each meta posts. Perhaps your comment should have been published after the judgement got delivered.

Comment: By the way, you'll be interested to know moderators burn through the comment queue pretty fast... raising a custom flag isn't going to expend any more time then a normal flag would've.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Your premise is flawed. Comment flags don't have their own review queue. Only moderators can see comment flags. So whichever flag you use, you *are* engaging our attention to review them. If you don't wish to hassle us with comment flags, you are not obligated to flag.

Comment: @BoltClock I will take that :) still learning the rules. But your comment potentially raises a dozen of counter questions.

Comment: The flag was marked helpful, and has now been deleted...

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks. It happened minutes within your comment was published here on meta :) _learnt the rule_, but now BoltClock's comments possibly gives a new dimension to this question I suppose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You said it yourself: the comment is no longer necessary because you added its contents into the question proper. Flagging the comment as "No Longer Needed" would suffice. Moderators seldom think twice about deleting comments, and I doubt they'd do a double take on a comment that isn't much more than a code dump.

However, if you want to be dead sure, you can raise a custom flag and explain that the comment is no longer needed since you edited it into the question. This is going to guarantee you a 99.9% probability of deletion unless there is a genuine mistake or severe lapse in judgement on the other end. This is usually how I get rid of code dump comments.

Comment: I'm not convinced a simple "no longer needed" flag for this type of thing will have a high success rate - in my experience, mods tend to not want to delete things that might potentially be useful, and such a flag doesn't make it clear that this has been edited into the post. Although posting code in a comment often leads to it being completely unreadable and generally useless - in such a case a "no longer needed" flag would presumably be more likely to be marked as helpful.

Comment: @Dukeling My experience is exactly the opposite. Almost all my flags are "no longer needed" flags on obsolete comments (I used to use "obsolete" back before the flags were rearranged) and I've got a 97% "helpful" rate over 2700 flags. (Not as high as some users - I recall previously seeing a couple of users mention having 99.9% "helpful" rates over tens of thousands of flags - but nonetheless a high rate.)

Comment: @Dukeling, my No Longer Needed flag was marked helpful just now.

Comment: Aren't there statistics available about the success rate of flagged "no longer needed" flags?